# Neo4j Desktop Fails to Open - Javascript Error

Tags: neo4j

When trying to start Neo4j Desktop, I'm getting a Javascript error. From the looks of it, it seems like the problem is with the desktop client (seems electron based) itself and not the database itself. Anyone encounter something similar or know how I could troubleshoot further? Running Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: what is th version of the desktop ? And yes it's an electron application.

Comment: Windows 7. Have updated the post with this info also.

Comment: and the neo4j desktop version ?

Comment: Latsest Version: 1.1.10

Comment: I never managed to solve this exact issue. However, given that neo4j desktop comes with neo4j server, I could start the server no problem and connect to localhost:7474 and access the web interface which served my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to solve this exact issue. However, given that neo4j desktop comes with neo4j server, I could start the server no problem and connect to localhost:7474 and access the web interface which served my needs.